# Using an array to substitute 10 random ints with corresponding strings

Tags: c#, arrays

I have created a very basic magic 8 ball programme as a learning exercise.
Currently it is outputting a random number between 0 - 9 every time i click the button.
I now want to finish off by substituting each of these numbers with a small description such as "the outlook looks good" or "there is a slim chance" etc etc.

I believe I need to use an array here however am not sure what kind of array I need and where the code needs to be nested.

Can anyone point me in the right direction.

Code so far...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Magic8ball
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private static int randomNumber;
        private const int rangeNumberMin = 0;
        private const int rangeNumberMax = 9;



        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            randomNumber = GenerateNumber(rangeNumberMin, rangeNumberMax);

        }

        private int GenerateNumber(int min, int max)
        {
            Random random = new Random();
            return random.Next(min, max);
        }

        private void Ask_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            int rn = randomNumber;

            if (textBox1.Text.Trim().Length == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please ask a question first", "No question was asked?");
            }

            else
            {
            MessageBox.Show("Number is" +" " + rn, "your answer...");
            textBox1.Text="";
            randomNumber = GenerateNumber(rangeNumberMin, rangeNumberMax);
            }

        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a regular array belonging to the class is probably the way to go. Since your random number starts from 0 you can use it as the array index `messages[randomNumber]`;

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private static int randomNumber;
    private const int rangeNumberMin = 0;
    private const int rangeNumberMax = 9;
    private readonly string[] messages = 
        {
            "I don't think so",
            "Maybe",
            "I don't think so",
            "Maybe",
            "I don't think so",
            "Maybe",
            "I don't think so",
            "Maybe",
            "I don't think so",
            "Yes",
        };

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        randomNumber = GenerateNumber(rangeNumberMin, rangeNumberMax);
    }

    private int GenerateNumber(int min, int max)
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        return random.Next(min, max);
    }

    private void Ask_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int rn = randomNumber;

        if (textBox1.Text.Trim().Length == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please ask a question first", "No question was asked?");
        }

        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Number is" +" " + rn, "your answer...");
            randomNumber = GenerateNumber(rangeNumberMin, rangeNumberMax);
            textBox1.Text = messages[randomNumber];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI I was using the textBox1.Text=""; to clear out the text after the programme gave a number/message. So I've put your messages[randomnumber] where it currently has the "Number is" + " " + rn and it works a treat. Many thanks!